# Managing Pages Library Inside Publishing Portal

Tags: publishing-site

I would like to know what is the best practice for managing the following scenario

- Publishing Portal with multiple authors
- I have defined multiple content types and added them to the Pages library
- each content type must be managed by different set of users

What should be done to make each user only able to create specific content type.

also I would like to mention that I am looking forward a proactive approach because each content type contains a lot of fields so I don't like to make my user enter all the fields then tell him "ooops you are not allowed to create that content type"

Answer (score 0):

I would create a sub site per content type (eg : news, press releases, articles) and aggregate them on the level above if needed through a content query webpart.

That would allow you to add contributors only at the sub web level and limit the number of available page layout to just the one(s) associated with the relevant content types. On other sub sites, the other contributors are just readers so no harm can be done.

I would then just be a matter of training them go just a little bit deeper (SPWeb -1) rather than where there are if they enter by the main SPWeb aggregating all the content type information.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but actually this solution would be hard to implement inside my project because the hierarchy already large so it will complicate things for the administrator